# How to sort Map by value in desc and key in natural order at the same time in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

There is any way to sort a Map by key and value at the same operation.
Map has value `{hover=1, solar=1, waterproof=3, storage=1, battery=2}`

So after sorting value should be

```
{waterproof=3, battery=2, hover=1, solar=1, storage=1}
```

I am trying to as

```
    Map mp = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
            (newValue,oldValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new))
        //.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())           
        //.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
        //(newValue,oldValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new))
            ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a comparator chain using [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
Map mp = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue())
                    .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (newValue, oldValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Note that in this case, you need to specify explicit type arguments for the first comparator, as compiler cannot infer types in such a complex case.